# KL divergence of continuous pdfs

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, pymc

Say I have two pdfs, e.g.:

```
from scipy import stats
pdf_y = stats.beta(5, 9).pdf
pdf_x = stats.beta(9, 5).pdf
```

I would like to  compute their [KL divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KL_divergence). Before I reinvent the wheel, are there any builtins in the PyData eco-system for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

KL divergence is available in scipy.stats.entropy. From the docstring

```
stats.entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None) 

Calculate the entropy of a distribution for given probability values.           

If only probabilities `pk` are given, the entropy is calculated as              
``S = -sum(pk * log(pk), axis=0)``.                                             

If `qk` is not None, then compute a relative entropy (also known as             
Kullback-Leibler divergence or Kullback-Leibler distance)                       
``S = sum(pk * log(pk / qk), axis=0)``.
```

Comment: Where did you find this? I couldn't the function on the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/stats.html)

Comment: I'm familiar with the source. There's an issue now to add it to the docs. Must have been oversight. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3420

Comment: But this doesn't work for continuous distributions according to the docs. What could you use there?

Comment: lack the points to downrate this answer. can't use stats.entropy with beta distributions since we're dealing with the continuous case

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the package `nimfa` has what you're looking for. http://nimfa.biolab.si

```
V = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])
fctr = nimfa.mf(V, method = "lsnmf", max_iter = 10, rank = 3)
fctr_res = nimfa.mf_run(fctr)
# Print the loss function according to Kullback-Leibler divergence. By default Euclidean metric is used.
print "Distance Kullback-Leibler: %5.3e" % fctr_res.distance(metric = "kl")
```

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, since it appears to only take one input, but it may be a place to start.

Additionally, this link could be useful. Seems to have some code (not with numpy) to compute the same thing.
https://code.google.com/p/tackbp2011/source/browse/TAC-KBP2011/src/python-utils/LDA/kullback-leibler-divergence.py?r=100

Answer (score 1):

Since KL-divergence is defined as an [integral for the continuous case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) I'm afraid you will have to do a [Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) over the (hyper) space for the two distributions.

In your case this would mean uniformly drawing random numbers in the interval [0,1] and calculating the two PDF's values, to be used in the integral calculation.

Comment: If we know what distributions are used there might be a closed form solution. For beta distributions asked in question one can derive closed-form solution.

Unfortunately it's not doable for all combinations of distributions.

Answer (score 1):

In other answers there are empiric KL-divergence calculations, while we can have a closed-form solution for Beta distributions as in question.

I was not able to find snippet with KL-div for beta distibutions on the web. In the end I coded it myself.

Sharing it as it might be useful for others:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

def kl(a1, b1, a2, b2):
  """https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution"""
  B = special.beta
  DG = special.digamma
  return np.log(B(a2, b2) / B(a1, b1)) + (a1 - a2) * DG(a1) + (b1 - b2) * DG(b1) + (
        a2 - a1 + b2 - b1) * DG(a1 + b1)
```